# Linear equation with prescribed precision of result

Tags: numerical-methods

Let $x$ be an unknown real vector of size n.

Suppose we can find n vectors $v_i$, and are given the values $x^Tv_i$.
Then we can simply solve for $x$ by Gauss or some other method and determine $x$ uniquely and precisely( iff $v_i$ are lin indep).

However, suppose now that we are only given the values $x^Tv_i$ up to some finite precision, then we might still find $x$, but also only up to a certain finite precision.

In the ideal infinite precision case, we would not gain anything by working with more than n vectors $v_i$, as we can already compute x uniquely. 
However, it seems that increasing n might help to determine $x$ with higher precision or maybe arbitrary precision even though the values $x^Tv_i$ have a fixed bounded precision. 
Of course this would be easy if we could freely choose the  $v_i$, be just choosing very large values.

So suppose this is not possible. ie suppose that $v_i$ are given randomly and the norm of  $v_i$ is bounded. What numerical methods are available, to determine x.

Assume that computation can be done with infinite precision

Answer (score 2):

Using more vectors (say, $m$) than the dimension of the space (say, $n$) means using a *frame* (as opposed to a basis). Your question is about the recovery from noisy frame coefficients.

Let $x_1,\dots,x_m$ be the frame vectors, and let $e_1,\dots e_n$ be a basis of $\mathbb R^n$. Then for each $j=1,\dots,n$ we have an $m$-dimensional vector vectors $(x_1^Te_j,\dots , x_m^Te_j)$. These vectors span the $n$-dimensional subspace $A$ in $\mathbb R^m$.  The most basic idea (which seems to work well sometimes) is to orthogonally project your vector of noisy coefficients  onto $A$, and reconstruct $x$ from this projection.

[The book](http://books.google.com/books?id=trZM8tKSnkAC) *Frames and bases: an introductory course* by Ole Christensen discusses this topic and gives references to the literature. A relevant subject is *quantized* frame expansions, in which the coefficients are subject to rounding. E.g., [this paper](http://signal.ese.wustl.edu/MURI/publications/01624636.pdf).

Comment: See also Christensen's [An Introduction to Frames and Riesz Bases](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783319256115), now in its second edition.